# How to have synchronize two git bare repositories?

Tags: git, cron, cron-task

Is possible to clone a git bare repo as a new bare repo ? for example:

- git init --bare mainRepo.git

Then in a remote server:

- git clone --bare xxx@server:/path/mainRepo.git repoReplica.git

And then with a cron job send changes from repoReplica.git to mainRepo.git, so I can have 2 teams working, one directly with mainRepo.git and the second with repoReplica.git

Is it possible ? and How ?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, but I would suggest for your synchronisation process to:

- not use cron
- use a [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) which can then push what has been receive to the other repo
- limit the synchronization to one branch
- use different branches

Meaning:

- `repo1` would push `master` to `repo2` as `master_fromrepo1`

  ```
  git push repo2 master:master_fromrepo1
  ```
- repo2 would push `master` to to `repo1` as `master_fromrepo2`

  ```
  git push repo1 master:master_fromrepo2
  ```

Comment: thanks @VonC, I've to read to use that. But, Why Do you suggest to use different branches ?

Comment: @MadMad666 to ensure fast-forward push, instead of potential merge conflicts if one unique branch is used for pushing from both repos.