# Git setup with online & offline computers

Tags: linux, git, github

I'm fairly new to git. I want to setup git for use at work. At work my main PC doesn't have access to the internet. I'm thinking of creating a bare git repo on a server that has access to the internet and have this be the main repo for my co-workers on other PCs.

Is there a way a to have this server forward to a remote repo like GitHub? This way we will have an offsite backup of our work that can accessed if we are away from the office. What is the best practices to do this? Can a bare git repo have a remote? If you have a better way to do what I want or I'm missing something please let me know.

Other considerations:
The server that will host the bare git repo will not be able to be accessed remotely.
All systems a RHEL
Some services like mail are forwarded
Will mostly be hosting BASH & python scripts, and dotfiles

Any help would be great.

Comment: You might want to look at e.g. Gitea for a lightweight GitHub/GitLab/... alternative to run on that server: https://about.gitea.com/

Comment: Why `python` and `bash` tags? What will be hosted is irrelevant, IMHO

Comment: @AKX I can't install extra software unless it is approved by my comapany

Comment: @buran your right I removed the extra tags

Comment: Okay, too bad. Well, yes, you can mirror a bare repo to a remote repository (`git push --mirror`).

Comment: @AKX mirror, I will have to look into that. Thank you

Comment: What are you allowed to do on the internal server? SSH interactive sessions (from the internal network)? Prepare bash or python scripts to be launched by a cron? Or do you intend to use another machine (maybe you private one) as a relay between the internal git server and github?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm the sys admin for the systems so I can do almost anything as long as it doesn't break any Security rules. I don't control the external firewall. None of the scripts are used by cron.  Yes, I intend to have an internal git server. I want that server to forward some of my scripts to github. I'm still very new to git.

Answer (score 0):

Git is perfectly suited for use cases, where repositories are not directly connected via HTTP. Linux kernel development, for which Git was initially conceived, happens to a large part via a mailing list. Therefore Git comes with tools to create and apply patches manually.

This gist details the process in 4 sentences: https://gist.github.com/nepsilon/22bc62a23f785716705c

A more featureful approach is to use [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch), then `git apply` in the other repo to apply the patch. Use [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) to automatically apply patches in a mailbox. (But you could equally well move the patches around on a USB stick.)

These tools are the building blocks that you can use to build your solution around the concrete requirements you have.

One word of caution: Before you set up a net-reachable repository where you place company-owned code from an internal repo, be 100% sure (best in writing), that you are allowed to do so.

Comment: +1 here the key is probably not what is technicaly possible - what you describe is - but what will be allowed by your company security officer... Github does allow *private* repos, but even there everything is accessible to github staff, not speaking of other possible security flaws.

Comment: @Boldewyn I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for.  I'm not really applying patches. I'm just updating BASH and python scripts.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I already talked to my security officer, and I'm allowed to do this. I'm also involved with the network security at work. As long as I sanitize the files, I'm fine. I can put any sensitive info into files that the script references and add them to the gitignore file. Thank you for bringing up this concern.

Comment: “Applying patches” is actually all that Git does under the hood. If you run `git log -p` you (more or less) see the patches that Git stores internally. When you update a script, i.e., you modify it, then do a `git add` and `git commit`, Git calculates the difference between what it currently has stored and what you want it to have stored and acts only on this difference, i.e. a patch.

Comment: @Boldewyn You might have given me the fix. I'm still new to git and when you mentioned patches it though me off. I was thinking along the lines of adding features. Thank you for patient me. I was hoping I could do some simular to mail forwarding. For example, the PCs not connected to the internet at my work site can send email via a mail forwarder.

Comment: Yes, I had something like this in mind when I mentioned `git am`. However, any concrete solution depends highly on what you can actually do with the machines, therefore it’s hard to give a more detailed suggestion for a setup.

Comment: @Boldewyn Thanks for your help so far. I'm still trying to figure stuff out. I will try the git am and see if it works.

Comment: By the way, look into @SergeBallesta’s answer, too! A good idea is to make use of Git hooks to trigger automation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself, but according to the doc it should not be too hard...

I can see 2 distinct points in you question:

1. Set up a git service on the local server.

   You have different options here:

   - a repository on a shared folder

     The good news is that all the access details, including authentication and authorizations are managed at no cost by the host. The downside, is that no git process is running on the system, so you will have to *manually* start the synchronization scripts to forward the changes to the external github site. You could launch them by hand through an interactive session, or use scheduled tasks or cron tasks.
   - a mere git daemon

     The good news is that it is trivial to setup, and you will be able to setup a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to automatically launch a synchronization script to update the external github site per each commit. The downside is that the git protocol has no provision for authentication nor authorization, so any user on the local network will be able to access to the repo.
   - a git service hosted in an Apache HTTP server

     Here again, hooks will be available to automate synchronization to the external GitHub. And thanks to Apache, you now have provision for authentication and authorizations. The downside is that in addition to the git server itself, you now have an apache configuration to maintain
   - an integrated application like GitWeb, GitLab or Gitea

     Just a variation from the previous way. Those applications offer additional goodies when viewing the repo from a browser at the cost of a slightly more complex configuration and  some more software to add on the internal server
2. Synchronize the local repo with a remote GitHub

   It should be possible according to this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24454386/3545273). But you should not allow anybody except the local git service to commit changes on the backup because the hooks only provide a single way sync from the local to the remote. Setting up a two way sync could be much harder...

Comment: Wow this is a lot of options. Looks like I will need to look into hooks. I can't do an Apache HTTP server. I can do a GitLab, but I'm not sure I can do the other two. Thanks I will have to do some reading